# Passing octal value to new number function

Tags: javascript, numbers, prototype-programming, octal

I've made something like :

```
Number.prototype.foo = function () {
    //code
}

// Octal number!
(013).foo();
```

But inspecting this inside of foo function, I get 11 as value... What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What did you expect to happen?

Javascript treats all whole numbers that start with a zero as octal[*] so the actual value of `013` is indeed `11` (decimal).  The `Number` class only deals in values, and won't know that you originally passed in an octal constant.

[*] There's an exception for whole numbers containing the digits 8 or 9 - since those aren't legal in octal the parser will implicitly treat them as decimal even in the presence of a leading zero.

Comment: @thom then you can't use the `Number` class.  Or whenever you've done what you want with the value, you have to convert it back into an octal _string_.

Answer (score 0):

An octal number is no different from a decimal number once it's been interpreted as a number.

`013` is exactly the same as `11`.  Once JavaScript sees that it's a number, it's just a number - it doesn't remember its "octalness" or "decimalness".

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a problem as you can convert it back to an octal representation easily:

```
var dec = 11;
alert(dec.toString(8)); // returns "13"
```

Numbers are returned in decimal format, but the numerical operations on it won't be any different as far as I know. Note also that *all* octal numbers supplied to JavaScript will be immediately "converted" in this fashion:

```
alert(013); // returns 11
```